# How can I do things like bold/highlight/change the font on only the text that I select?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text-editor, text-manipulation

I'm making a simple word processor and I want to be able to change the font/style (or whatever it's called) of only the text that I highlight.

I can't say what I've tried because I don't even know where to start.

```
from tkinter import *
# window setup
tk = Tk()
# main textbox
textbox = Text(tk)
textbox.configure(width=85,height=37)
textbox.grid(column=0,row=0,rowspan=500)
# bold
def bold():
    textbox.config(font=('Arial',10,'bold'))
bBut = Button(tk,text='B',command=bold)
bBut.configure(width=5,height=1)
bBut.grid(column=0,row=0)
tk.mainloop()
```

I can change the entire text to bold/italic/etc. but I want to be able to specify parts of it.

Comment: you can assign "tag" to selected text and define color for this tag. Example: [tkinter/tags](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/tags)

Comment: This is all documented wherever you find documentation for the text widget. Search for "tags" or "tag". Also, this site has many questions related to highlighting words in a text widget.

Answer (score 0):

It use `tags` to assign color or font to text

```
import tkinter as tk

def set_bold():
    try:
        textbox.tag_add('bold', 'sel.first', 'sel.last')
    except Exception as ex:
        # text not selected
        print(ex)

def set_red():
    try:
        textbox.tag_add('red', 'sel.first', 'sel.last')
    except Exception as ex:
        # text not selected
        print(ex)

root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root)
textbox.pack()

textbox.tag_config('bold', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))
textbox.tag_config('red', foreground='red')

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Bold', command=set_bold)
button1.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Red', command=set_red)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```